# SharedPreferences в отдельном классе

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь загрузить сохраненную строку в отдельном классе сл способом

```
public class Load extends AppCompatActivity{

public Load(){

}

public String crip(){

sPref = getSharedPreferences("key", MODE_PRIVATE);

ld = sPref.getString(KEY,"");

return   ld;

    }

}
```

пытаюсь получить строку из другого класса таким образом

```
Load losd = new Load();
```

load.crip() вот это я пытаюсь вывести в логи  но при запуске андроид студио ссылается на нулевой объект
вот здесь

```
sPref = getSheredPreferences("key", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: Всё плохо. Активити это монстрический объект, который при создании которого очень много всего инитится. А Вы переопределили конструктор, буквально сломали создание объекта, а потом пытаетесь вытащить из него то, чего в нём нет и быть не может

Comment: Если хотите доставать значения отдельным классом, то можно сделать следующее. Создать синглтон, проинитить его AppContext'om в onCreate в классе application, создать в нем функцию, которая обращаясь к апп контексту достает из него префсы и сроку и пользоваться этим.

Comment: можно сделать то же и инитить контекстом активити, но это бэд паттерн, потому что надо делать осторожно,а то полезут мемори лики. По крайней мере ссылку на контекст активити хранить нигде не надо, тогда будет ок.

Comment: активити - глубоко интегрированный в систему компонент с жизненным циклом, управляемым системой и этой же системой и создаваемый. Нельзя просто так взять, создать обычный пользовательский объект и думать, что он будет "живой" активити. Это примерно, как пытаться завести и ехать на пустом кузове от машины. Вся эта схема полностью не рабочая и работать не будет

Comment: для доступа к преференсам вообще не нужна активити, а нужен только Context. вы можете решить это, как предложено во втором комментарии или просто передавать "живой" контекст в свой класс, если есть такая возможность. использовать тогда `pref = context.getSheredPreferences("key", MODE_PRIVATE);`